# Is it bad to trust PHP's $_SERVER information?

Tags: php

I want to know if is bad to trust the PHP's global variable $_SERVER values.

I have a scenario that I change between developer and production site, and I have a config.php file. On this file, I check $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] value, to determine which group of constants I should use. If I'm on production environment I use a list A of constants, if I'm on developer environment I use another list of constants.

Does this make my PHP project vulnerable in any way?

Comment: To answer more broadly: some elements in the `$_SERVER` variable are user-provided, and some are not.  Don't trust the ones that are user provided.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474783/which-server-variables-are-safe

Comment: @ConorMancone if I limit the acceptable values that comes from a user-provided data, like using a array that keeps a white list of valid domains, the project still vulnerable?

Answer (score 1):

A: yes... from the perspective of the trailing question, *"Does this make my PHP project vulnerable in any way?"*

I'll assume that in the config file you have salt/pepper, database credentials, and other parameters that you might find in an *ownCloud* or *Wordpress* config.php file, the sort of which would hold value for an adversary.

If your config.php is exposed in your lower environment, you are making production-environment configuration parameters available in this file. Just about anything can happen in a dev environment, where as *hopefully* your production environment is a little more locked down. The potential for exposure is greater by having all the configuration parameters in the one file.

And for the rigid interpretation of your question...
A: no

Your config.php file would not in any way be *less safe* if you had an if/else or other branching conditional and the logic was correct. The potential for the contents of this file to be exposed under normal `php` and web server operation is no different than if you had separate files per environment. With respect to *safe*, [see the other answer that @mti2935 linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474783/which-server-variables-are-safe) (in a comments against this question) that discusses the safety of the variables in the `$_SERVER` dict, ie. which parameters can be influenced by the user.

Another observation - with a branching conditional, you're relying on correct implementation of the web server and `php` interpreter to prevent the user influencing the contents of the `$_SERVER` dict. I don't have time at the moment to find an example, but there's a large number of vulnerability records to wade through: https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/search/results?form_type=Basic&results_type=overview&query=%24_SERVER&queryType=phrase&search_type=last3years

Comment: I think the question was more about using `$_SERVER` variables.

Comment: Hi, @brynk.. I considered that. But I'm trying to understand how this config file could turn things bad on my project. The file doesn't print out anything, i'ts just a list of constants inside a if/else block that checks $_SERVER['name'] value. 
Before that, on the beginning of the script, I have a domain check that kills the script if the request comes from a not allowed URL. Even with that check, the project still vulnerable? Why?